# Weird interaction ng-hide and data-charts angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my piece of HTML code (please ignore not closed tags):

```
<div class="row" ng-hide="hideCaptiveRow">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div data-ac-chart="'pie'" 
                 data-ac-data="memCaptive.status.data" 
                 data-ac-config="memCaptive.status.config" 
                 class="chart">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, `hideCaptiveRow` is a boolean value that changes at front end from a drop box choice. It perfectly hides and shows the div but when going from `ng-hide = true` to `ng-hide = false`, only the div is displayed, not the `data-ac-chart`.

However if I hover with the mouse on other charts present in the page that chart is refreshed graphically and get shown.

I cannot find a way to refresh/re-draw that specific chart without refreshing the hole page or calculate again the data source (that actually works but it is a total waste of resources).

Is there a simple way involving only HTML and AngularJS to do that, without using Ajax / JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Put the chart data and config in a function and call it whenever you set the value of hideCaptiveRow to false.

```
$scope.renderChart = function(){
    var memCaptive.status.config ={.....}
}
```

When you set hideCaptiveRow call the function:

```
$scope.hideCaptiveRow = false;
$scope.renderChart()
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for you answer darkkinght but it was still not refreshing the graph.

However i found out that was some kind of bug with ng-show.

**ng-if** was the solution.